# If i can deploy an ERC 20 to an exchange and sell it is it technically free money?

Tags: tokens, ether, exchanges

Can you deploy an erc 20 token to an exchange?

Can you sell your own erc 20 for money?

Is this free money because when you deploy it, it gives you all the erc 20 to your address.

Comment: Simple Question/Answer: Why would anyone pay any money to get that token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So ik you can deploy an erc 20 token to an exchange

A centralised exchange will only list your token if they think they can make a profit from it.

You can list your token on a  decentralised exchange or AMM but you'll have to provide the liquidity of any pools you create, meaning you have to put money in.

> can you sell your own erc 20 for money

Only if someone will buy it. Otherwise it is worthless.

> Because when you delpoy it it automaticly gives you all the erc 20 to ur adress.

Anyone doing their due diligence will read the contract and will likely not buy your token.